# Building a multi-platform container image using Quarkus and GraalVM Native Image?

Tags: containers, quarkus, graalvm-native-image, buildx

I am wondering if the quarkus-container-image-docker (or jib) extensions can produce a multi-platform container image with a natively-compiled executable. (In particular, I'm interested in linux/amd64 + linux/arm64.)

I have a sample github repo (https://github.com/wlfgang/buildx-example/tree/main) that sets the property `quarkus.docker.buildx.platform=linux/arm64,linux/amd64`, but the output image only seems to run on amd64. On arm64, it gives `exec ./application: exec format error`. GraalVM build output also seems to indicate it is only getting built for amd64.

Maybe what I'm trying to do isn't supported? I couldn't find a clear answer in the Quarkus docs.